# Use Excel Cube functions with Azure Analysis Services Tabular Model

Tags: excel, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

Is it possible to connect to a tabular model in Azure Analysis Services with Excel and then use the built in Cube functions like CUBESET?

My google-fu has failed to provide me with an answer

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've used cube functions against on-premise SSAS and datasets in the Power BI Service, so I'd be shocked if you couldn't with Azure AS. You create a connection to the Analysis Services from **Data > Get Data** in Excel and then reference the connection name in the cube function.